# How can I set a default search query in vue-multiselect component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am using vue-multiselect. https://vue-multiselect.js.org

My template looks something like this.

```
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" searchable="true"></multiselect>
```

By default, when I open the multiselect, the search query is empty.

I want the default search query to equal to v-model.

Answer (score 1):

```
<multiselect 
  ...
  :searchable="true"
  ref="inputInstance"
>
</multiselect>

data: () => ({
  ...
}),
methods: {
  setSearchValue(v) {
    this.$refs.inputInstance.handleSearchInput({
      target: {
        value: v
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

Single Selection:

```
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :custom-label="nameWithLang" placeholder="Select one" label="name" track-by="name"></multiselect>

data: () => ({
    value: {name: 'MyValue', text: 'MyText'},
    options: [{name: 'MyValue', text: 'MyText'}]
}),
methods: {
    methods: {
        nameWithLang ({ name, text }) {
          return `${name} — [${text}]`
        }
      }
}
```

Multilple selection:

```
data: () => ({
    value: [{name: 'MyValue', text: 'MyText'}],
    options: [{name: 'MyValue', text: 'MyText'}]
})
```

Comment: This is setting the selected value as nameWithLang value. However, the search query still remains the same.

Comment: Difficult to post my example, but even with your code, which I see is from the official website, after clicking on the custom label, the label disappears and a search input box with placeholder 'Select One' appears. I want the set a default value for this search input box and not be empty by default.

Comment: Put a minimal example of how you are using it.
https://jsfiddle.net/shentao/jqofkzxc/

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ws60r57j/). Notice how on clicking on the select the search box is always empty. I want the default search value to be the selected value and not be empty.

Comment: See if this solves your problem @KaranBains
https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/unc17f3p/2/

Comment: It's a work around, but it seems that's the only to get it done. Thanks for the help.